# CloudStore vs. HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Does anyone have any familiarity with working with both [CloudStore](http://kosmosfs.sourceforge.net/features.html) and HDFS. I am interested to see how far CloudStore has been scaled and how heavily it has been used in production. CloudStore seems to be more full featured than HDFS. When thinking about these two filesystems what practical trade offs are there?

Answer (score 3):

Steve, It seems that CloudStore should be faster than the HDFS as it's designed in C++. We are also interested in this Comparision and planning to use this in production.

Let us know if you find anything interesting in this regards.

Comment: "As it's designed in C++"? For distributed file-systems, where the performance issues do not usually stem directly from computational load, I would expect algorithms to weigh in quite a bit more heavily than languages.

Comment: Depends on scale. At low scale that is correct. If a managed language imposes say a 10% overhead then you have to have 10% more servers. At a certain point it is cheaper to write something in c++ than buy 10% more servers. I know most people don't have that problem but I soon will.

Answer (score 1):

CloudStore (or KFS) is now Quantcast File System (or QFS). The project currently resides at https://github.com/quantcast/qfs, and has a [comparison with HDFS](https://github.com/quantcast/qfs/wiki/Performance-Comparison-to-HDFS) page you can take a look at.